# standard ethernet pinout for M12 A coded

Tags: connector, ethernet, pinout, standard, rj45

I would love to follow the most common pinout (I design connector and receptable, but you never know).

I find conflicting sources:

-RJ45 connector exact same pinout number by number: [image: Folloing RJ45 plug pinout literally 1 is 1, 2 is 2, .... 8 is 8]

-A big cable producing brand Turck seems to have another "standard", I did see this at one of our clients:
[image]

Or, is there no (de facto) standard?

UPDATE: we are using the Turck standard on all our cables now. This seems the de facto standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mouser M12 Vs RJ45](http://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/PhoenixContactM12_vs_RJ45_White_Paper.PDF)

On page 2 of this info sheet from Phoenix Contact, it says 
"There is still no agreed standard on wiring an eight-pin variant for Industrial Ethernet."

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks.  FYI   I got an answer back from Turck. They labeled their own pinout as  "CORRECT" and the pin-by-pin with RJ45 connectors as "INCORRECT"  (but I guess, that's their view :) )

Comment: Here's also an HTML version of the linked article: https://iebmedia.com/index.php?id=5873&parentid=63&themeid=255&showdetail=true

Answer (score 2):

Below a table I made of the most widely used standard I have seen. Hope this helps someone out. This does match the "Turck" standard.

[image]

Comment: This confirms the "Turck" layout from in the question. I have indeed not seen other layouts since.

Answer (score 0):

OR this.

[image]

<sup>Source: https://bilder.tragant.de/produkte/orig/5c51a102e4ef30.77076833.jpg</sup>

I use M12 A-code. But I decided to use the same standard as X-code.
We now always order cables from China.

[image]

<sup>Source: https://bilder.tragant.de/produkte/orig/5d7f5208916659.72117111.jpg</sup>